# Why is parameterized Cypher query is taking longer time compared to unparameterized query when using a default planner

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j-2.2.1 and using Transactional Cypher Restful Endpoint to query. I am trying to match email nodes using the following query

```
match (e:Email) where e.email in ['gxxxxxxs@yyy.com'] return count(e);
```

The email property in Email node has a unique constraint on it and therefore has a index built automatically around it. The above query took 23 seconds when I ran it using query parameters as in `{"statements": [{"parameters": {"emails": ["gxxxxxxs@yyy.com"]}, "statement": "match (c:Email) where c.email in {emails}  return count(c)"}]}` where as it took only 0.0134 seconds when I ran it directly without any parameters as in
 `{"statements": [{"statement": "match (c:Email) where c.email in ['gxxxxxxs@yyy.com'] return count(c)"}]}`

I tried to profile it to see how the query is executed and to my surprise, the parameterized query was not using the unique index seek which I expected it to use.

The results of the profiling as given below -

### **Profile of Non-Parameterized Query**

> {"statements": [{"statement": "PROFILE match (c:Email) where c.email in ['gxxxxxxs@yyy.com'] return count(c)"}]}

{"results":[{"columns":["count(c)"],"data":[{"row":[1]}],"plan":{"root":{"operatorType":"EagerAggregation","DbHits":0,"Rows":1,"**version":"CYPHER 2.2**","KeyNames":"","EstimatedRows":1.0000000000279299,"**planner":"COST**","identifiers":["count(c)"],"children":[{"**operatorType":"NodeUniqueIndexSeek**","Index":":Email(email)","Rows":1,"DbHits":1,"EstimatedRows":1.00000000005586,"identifiers":["c"],"children":[]}]}}}],"errors":[]}

**Finished in 0.0134048461914 sec**

### **Profile of Parameterized Query**

> {"statements": [{"parameters": {"emails": ["gxxxxxx@yyy.com"]}, "statement": "PROFILE match (c:Email) where c.email in {emails}  return count(c)"}]}
>   {"results":[{"columns":["count(c)"],"data":[{"row":[1]}],"plan":{"root":{"operatorType":"EagerAggregation","DbHits":0,"Rows":1,"**version":"CYPHER 2.2**","KeyNames":"","EstimatedRows":1384.8193022918188,"**planner":"COST**","identifiers":["count(c)"],"children":[{"operatorType":"Filter","LegacyExpression":"any(-*-INNER-*- in {emails} where c.email == -*-INNER-*-)","Rows":1,"DbHits":5114522,"EstimatedRows":1917724.4999999998,"identifiers":["c"],"children":[{"**operatorType":"NodeByLabelScan**","LabelName":":Email","Rows":2557261,"DbHits":2557262,"EstimatedRows":2556966.0,"identifiers":["c"],"children":[]}]}]}}}],"errors":[]}

**Finished in 23.5868499279 sec**

Can someone please help me understand why a parameterized cypher query is not using the unique index seek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reported bug in Cypher since 2.2+. ( IN not using indexes with parameters )

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4357

You can avoid this by prefixing your query with **PLANNER RULE** in order to use the previous Cypher planner and gain performance until the bug is fixed.

```
PLANNER RULE MATCH (e:Email) where e.email IN {emails} RETURN count(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for your parameterized query, the Cypher engine is not inferring the correct schema index  to use and so is doing a scan. Ordinarily, the cypher engine needs to infer where in the graph to start the query by looking at the `MATCH` clause and the `WHERE` conditions and using that information to find a useful index.

You can ask it to use a specific index with `USING`. So if your Cypher query was something like this

```
MATCH (c:Email) 
USING INDEX c:Email(email)
WHERE c.email in ['gxxxxxxs@yyy.com'] 
RETURN count(c)
```

you should find that the query is executed using a `NodeUniqueIndexSeek`. The equivalent would be

```
{
    "statements": [{
        "parameters": {
            "emails": ["gxxxxxxs@yyy.com"]
        }, 
        "statement": "MATCH (c:Email) 
                      USING INDEX c:Email(email) 
                      WHERE c.email IN {emails} 
                      RETURN count(c)"
    }]
}
```

(line breaks added for readibility)